# Cannot figure out how my nodejs application run with apache

Tags: htaccess, apache, node-js

I need to push my node app updates to remote host which is really wired. It uses standard cPanel + apache bundle, but also has node installed.
Root domain `mywired.host` hosts static files from `public_html`.
Subdomain `api.mywired.host` is looking to a dir with following `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]    {32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

And the fun part is that there's two node applications running now, first uses port 3001, second 3002.
And if I send queries to `api.mywired.host/fisrt` I got a response from 3001 port app, and when I send it to the the `api.mywired.host/second` I get response from 3002 port app. 
I literally cannot figure out how this magic works, and I feel afraid to `kill` old application and run the fresh ones.